# Making a TS cable with a 3-conductor wire

Tags: wiring, cables

I want to make a guitar cable (standard 1/4 inch TS - tip-sleeve plugs). I have the appropriate plugs, but a 3-conductor (two leads and sleeve) wire. So I need to leave one conductor unused.

What is my best option? Using the two "inner" conductors and leave the sleeve uwired, or using one of the inner conductors and the sleeve?

Comment: My bad! Yes, I meant 'conductor'. I edited the text to incorporate this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I'd probably do is to use the shield for one connection (ring) and the put the two inner conductors in parallel for the tip connection.

It costs you nothing to use both inner conductors except for stripping and soldering two wires instead of one.  It gets you lower resistance, which might be needed in a long cable.  It also gets you a little redundancy - if one wire breaks the other is still connected.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for the inner-sleeve conductors configuration. Leaving the sleeve out can deteriorate your signal since it's also meant to shield electromagnetic noises. The other "inner" conductor can be left disconnected without any concerns.